# undefined reference to `log'

Tags: c, math, random, makefile, ld

I am trying to compile the implementation of the RFC 3797 random selection algorithm by Donald Eastlake (code: http://kambing.ui.ac.id/minix/other/rfc3797/). However, I am getting a linker error:

```
rfc3797.c:(.text+0xe7f): undefined reference to `log'
```

I am trying to make it with the provided Makefile, which explicitly links against the math libraray, but I still get the error:

```
cc -lm -o randomselection rfc3797.c MD5.c
```

How can I compile this program?

Comment: Can you try `cc -o randomselection rfc3797.c MD5.c -lm` ?

Comment: @Shade No, it's okay, I'm glad it's working :-) You can accept fajrans answer instead. And here's a [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/lib/libsearch.html) on the subject.

Comment: Trying to implement an RFC -> get compile-time errors -> take the error to google (which is really quite a generic error) -> top result is someone else having an issue with that same RFC. There is some beauty to that.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I don't know what the reason is, but if you move `-lm` to the end, it will compile.

```
$ cc -o randomselection rfc3797.c MD5.c -lm
rfc3797.c: In function ‘getinteger’:
rfc3797.c:183:3: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
```

Comment: To expand on what Kerrek is referring to, and borrowing from cnicutar above, this explains how linking works with reference to argument order: http://c-faq.com/lib/libsearch.html