# Nist Sphere format files

Tags: speech-recognition

In order to read NIST sphere format files, I'm trying to install NIST SPHERE software downloaded from [here](http://www.itl.nist.gov/iad/mig//tools/), but I encountered some errors:

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ibtissem/tools/nist/src/bin'
gcc  -I/home/ibtissem/tools/nist/include -L/home/ibtissem/tools/nist/lib -g -g -DNARCH_linux h_add.c  -lm -o h_add
h_add.c:31: error: undefined reference to 'sp_verbose'
h_add.c:31: error: undefined reference to 'sp_verbose'
h_add.c:28: error: undefined reference to 'hs_getopt'
h_add.c:42: error: undefined reference to 'sp_verbose'
h_add.c:42: error: undefined reference to 'sp_get_version'
h_add.c:44: error: undefined reference to 'hs_optind'
h_add.c:50: error: undefined reference to 'hs_optind'
h_add.c:53: error: undefined reference to 'hs_optind'
h_add.c:55: error: undefined reference to 'hs_optind'
h_add.c:71: error: undefined reference to 'sp_create_header'
h_add.c:93: error: undefined reference to 'sp_write_header'
h_add.c:103: error: undefined reference to 'sp_fpcopy'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [h_add] Error 1
```

Does someone have any idea about this error?

Comment: Which package exactly are you trying to compile? What are you steps. Which OS do you have. Remember, the more information you provide the faster you will get an answer.

Comment: Thank you Nikolay for your reply. I downloaded **sphere_2.6a.tar.Z** from [here](http://www.itl.nist.gov/iad/mig//tools/) on **ubuntu** But when I tried to install it with the command `sh src/scripts/install.sh` I had the errors listed above.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new version of sphere here：
http://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/mig/tools.cfm

The second tool in Corpus Building Tools. According to the readme file of the package, it has been tested on the following plantforms:

> Mac OS X (10.6)
>   Linux (Ubuntu 11.04)
>   Cygwin (1.7 under Windows XP)

Comment: another link found here ftp://jaguar.ncsl.nist.gov/pub/ but it's 2.6 version

Comment: To anyone using this version, I had to change `$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJ) $(PROJECT_ROOT)/lib/lib$(COMBINEDLIB).a
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $@.c $(OBJ) $(LLIBS) -o $@` to `$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJ) $(PROJECT_ROOT)/lib/lib$(COMBINEDLIB).a
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $@.c $(OBJ) $(LLIBS) -o $@ -lm
` in `lib/makes/make_spg.txt` because I was getting errors similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145264/undefined-reference-to-log

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using [Sound Exchange](http://sox.sourceforge.net/). It includes both a converter:

```
sox foo.sph foo.wav
```

As well as a simple player:

```
play foo.sph
```

It's also well-maintained and does all sorts of other useful things. You can easily download packages without compiling it.

Comment: Gives me the following error: `sph: unsupported coding alaw`

Comment: sox FAIL formats: can't open input file `/foo/bar.wav': WAVE: RIFF header not found

Answer (score 1):

sphere_2.6a.tar.Z is very outdated package not supported in modern systems

To decode SPHERE files download sph2pipe instead:

ftp://ftp.ldc.upenn.edu/pub/ldc/misc_sw/sph2pipe_v2.5.tar.gz

ftp://ftp.ldc.upenn.edu/pub/ldc/misc_sw/sph2pipe_v2.5.README_1ST