# Error: file does not start with RIFF id

Tags: python, audio, wav, wave

This line of code is throwing an error:

```
import wave
...
wave.open('/path/to/wavfile/1a.wav', "rb")
```

The 1a.wav is in the NIST SPHERE format. I don't have much experience with the wav formats, but is there anyway I could transform it into RIFF format so that I can open it with the "wave" library?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/37602426/120261, SoX should be able to convert SPHERE to WAV.

Answer (score 2):

Use ffmpeg to convert. e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i test.wav -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 16000 out.wav
```

Comment: Thanks, my file is an .AAC file but I used your command and it works too.